# Dealing with multiple possible inherited classes at runtime

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm making my first Windows Form Object Oriented program in C#.

I have a base class, ie: Game, with two possible inherited classes: VideoGame and BoardGame.

My MainForm should offer the possibility to create either a Game, VideoGame and BoardGame object and then offer several TextBoxes to input values for class attributes.

I'm trying to understand how I can deal with the possibility that there will be several possible different classes that will be created.

To explain myself better if I have:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
   private Game newGame = new Game();

   private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      newGame.Name = "Game Name";
   }
}
```

This would work if it was always going to be the Game class used. But my Form should offer the possibility to make this either a base class Game object, or a VideoGame subclass that would perhaps have a "Platform" attribute.

In this case I can't use the declared newGame attribute of MainForm because it is fixed to a Game object.

I realize that I'm perhaps being vague in my question, and I'm probably missing some knowledge of Object Oriented Programming, but general guide lines on how I would go around to implement such an application would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: Have a hierarchy of input forms corresponding to the hierarchy of games classes. The `BoardGameInputForm` class would know how to fill in the properties of the `BoardGame` class, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are muddling the use of derived classes somewhat by trying to understand them in this context. The purpose of a Game class would be to contain all of the methods and properties common to all derived types. Derived types would have additional properties and methods more specific to their context. Derived types may also override common methods such as startGame or endGame or gameOver.

You would probably never instantiate a Game object directly.

Your exercise muddles this slightly because you are talking about generating forms to set properties of the classes which is not really a responsibility of the Game types themselves. You would probably have a select box for the type of game which determines a) the fields available and b) the type of game to instantiate.

Once you have an instance of a Game object you can call any of the base methods or properties no matter if it is a videoGame or boardGame.